# Do not include string in match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to run regex on a string something like

`string = 'The value is ij35dss. The value is fsd53fdsfds.'`

Where I want something like `string.match(/The value is (.*?)\./g);`
 to return just `['ijdss','fsdfdsfds']`  and not `['The value is ijdss.', 'The value is fsdfdsfds.']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead, here's a sample:

```
var string = 'The value is ij35dss. The value is fsd53fdsfds.';
var re = new RegExp(/The value is (.*?)\./g)

var strs = []   
var m = re.exec(string)

while(m != null) {
  strs.push(m[1]);
  m = re.exec(string)
}

alert(strs)
```

and a jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WtTPd/

If you think you will need this often, you can add this to a String.prototype:

```
String.prototype.matchGroup = function(re, group) {
  var m = re.exec(string);
  var strs = [];
  while(m != null) {
    strs.push(m[group]);
    m = re.exec(string);
  }
  return strs;
}

var string = 'The value is ij35dss. The value is fsd53fdsfds.';
alert(string.matchGroup(/The value is (.*?)\./g, 1));
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WtTPd/1/

Credits:

- [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

Comment: See the edit - however, I don't see why you view it as "hackish". This is a normal way of using regexps - you match, then loop through all the matches and extract groups, seems pretty clean to me.

Comment: @BHare, it's not hackish, just badly written. Could be made nicer, like: http://jsfiddle.net/SutFc/

Comment: I understand its not "hackish" because there exists no method in javascript to do regex like any other language I've used; That's the part that seems hackish. That the function matchGroup, as simple as it is, doesn't exist natively.